# C#.NET Interactive Chart Control

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, charts

Googled around and couldn't find anything... essentially what I want to do is **allow the user to click and drag data points around to new values on a line graph control.**  The built-in chart control is pretty robust, but as far as I can tell, there's no way to add this kind of interactivity (am I overlooking something?).

I figured it would be a pretty hefty task to do this on my own, so I wondered if anyone had stumbled across this before and made a custom control to do it.

If not, any guidance on where the best place to start would be for making a custom control to do this?

Comment: for any kind of precision at all, values will probably need to be able  edited as input. I hate things that solely rely on the precision of my mouse and steadiness of my hate for accuracy.

Comment: Just Google "draggable charts" for a 3rd party control. You can find plenty of alternatives. For example HiCharts can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/AyUbx/1211/ (assuming you're talking about Web, but there should be alternatives for Winform/WPF as well)

Comment: I have used Telerik UI controls and their charts do provide some functionality that you will be interested in. Google it.

Answer (score 1):

Womp... solved my own question, turns out I was just Googling the wrong things.  Ended up implementing a version of this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2bc4823c-1365-40ee-a239-b6f0c65a539a/datapoint-drawing-position-and-interactivity?forum=MSWinWebChart

It essentially uses the HitTest method of the built-in chart control to determine what point was clicked on MouseDown and just changes that point's X and Y on the fly in the MouseMove event. Pretty nifty.

Comment: If you are happy with your own answer do accept it!